# How to process href parameters jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, model-view-controller

I have little test page, but I can't get request parameters an don't understand why.
Test page have "href" links like this:

```
<a href="main.jspc?param=show" class="submenu">Show smth</a>
```

Simple controller:

```
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Controller extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    protected void processRequest (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Do SMTH<br>");
        sb.append("Other will be later...<br>");
        String s = sb.toString();
        request.setAttribute("result", s);
        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("test.jsp");
        view.forward(request,response);
    }
}
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>main.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>controller</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>Controller</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>controller</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/main.jspc</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and test page, where i want to show some obtained parameters:

test.jsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<%
    out.print("<br>" + "Parameter: ");
    request.getParameter("param");
    out.print("<br>"+ "URL:");
    request.getRequestURL();
    out.print("<br>" + "Result:");
    request.getParameter("result");
%>
</body>
</html>
```

But test page showing empty parameters, I don't understand why.

Comment: Try using `${param.param}` and `${result}` on test.jsp

Comment: can you see <a href="main.jspc?param=show" class="submenu">Show smth</a>. I see here jspc.can you try to change it into jsp

Comment: How it would be in full correct version?

Comment: jspc - its mapped to Controller.java, i`m already have main.jsp - href links from there.

Comment: I found my mistake - instead of using method request.getParameter need to use request.getAttribute, because i set Attributes in there: request.setAttribute("result", s);

Answer (score 0):

The use of scriptlets (those <% %> things) in JSP is old one and discouraged since the birth of taglibs([JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)) and EL([Expression Language](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info), those ${} things).

Use below code access your parameter :

```
Parameter : ${params} <br>
Result : ${result} <br>
URL : ${pageContext.request.requestURI}
```